# keep running in background when application is closed just like whatapps message in notification

Tags: android

"when i was opened the application and **startService** send the notification but if i closed the my apps then never stop the apps and keep running my apps just like **phone message if u closed the message app but keep running** "

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Intent service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        service = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","beforeServiceCall");
        startService(service);
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","afterServiceCall");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","beforeServiceCallOnDestroyed");
        startService(service);
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","AfterServiceCallOnDestroyed");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}

public class CallService extends Service {

    public static int waitTime=10*1000;  //seconds

    //public static int defaultTime=15*60*1000; // default Minutes

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","onCreate Service");
        backgroundProcess();
    }

    public void backgroundProcess(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i=0;
                for(;;){
                   Log.i("JobServiceCall","run : "+i++);
                    OneTimeWorkRequest request=new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(WorkJob.class).build();
                    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                   }
                   catch (InterruptedException ie){
                       ie.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","service keep running on destroy");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
       // broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this,  RestartServiceOnBroadcastReceiver.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        Log.i("JobServiceCall","send Broadcast Receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

"output is when i open the app keep running and if my apps is closed then service stop itself "

"i want keep running my apps"

Comment: Have you tried using a ForegroundService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**You need to use a Foreground Service to keep alive background service**

public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        //do heavy work on a background thread


        //stopSelf();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }

}

------------------------------Start and Stop Forground Service----------------

public void startService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Foreground Service Example in Android");

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }

    public void stopService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }


 -----------------------------------Add Service in Manifest-------------------


 <service
            android:name=".ForegroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
```

Comment: keep running if my app is closed or swipe in recent apps??